# What are hobbies?

Tags: word-usage

Dictionaries give me only definition of this word. They don't give me exact examples. What are hobbies to those who are living in English spoken countries? Playing sports, reading books, going fishing, watching movies are hobbies?

Comment: This question seems very, _very_ broad - are you asking for a list of hobbies (which is far too broad, because it's essentially everything - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Hobbies) has a good list to start with), or a better definition of hobbies? Dictionaries don't always give examples, since generally, they only define terms.

Comment: It all hinges on *why* you do them.  To a professional sports player, sports is not a hobby, it's a job.  The same could be said of a book publisher, a fishing show host, a movie critic, etc.

Comment: I don't think the O.P. is asking for a complete list – just a better idea of what classifies as a hobby, and what doesn't. It may need to be fleshed out a little bit, but, if this question doesn't have a home here, I think we should just pack it in. (To the O.P., the answer to your question is "Yes" – playing sports, reading books, going fishing, and watching movies could all be considered _hobbies_.)

Comment: I think arguably anything can be claimed as a hobby by a person. If asking for some common hobbies, there are too many *English spoken countries* to make a stereotype. Assuming the OP is from Japan, I would say, for many English (or any other languages) speaking countries, not much is different from Japan.

Answer (score 2):

Hobbies are activities that you do regularly for fun, as opposed to things that you do for a living.  Generally, a hobby is something that you put time into and get pretty good at (an "amateur"), but you don't usually do it as well as someone who does it professionally (in other words, for a living).

For example, I make a living as a software analyst.  I also play piano quite well, which I do as a hobby.  I sing in karaoke bars regularly as well.  That's another hobby.  I used to be a member of a chess club and play in tournaments.  Another hobby.

My brother-in-law likes to fly radio-controlled airplanes.  That's a hobby as well. One of my brothers is also in software, but is also a very good amateur cartoonist.  Another hobby.

Hopefully, that gives you some examples that will clarify the idea.

Comment: Although I don't think skill level has anything to do with it.

Comment: Perhaps not.  I thought about that a bit, and I decided that there's a difference between a "dabbler" and a "hobbyist".  :)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, some dictionaries don't give precise examples. For example, [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hobby) only says:

> **hobby** (*n.*) an activity pursued in spare time for pleasure or relaxation

However, some dictionaries do give some helpful examples. For example, [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/hobby) mentions:

> **hobby** (*n.*) something that you enjoy doing when you are not working : *Mike's hobbies include reading and chess*.

and [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/hobby) says:

> **hobby** (*n.*) an activity that someone does for pleasure when they are not working : *Ben's hobby is restoring vintage motorcycles*.

NOAD states:

> **hobby** (*n.*) an activity done regularly in one's leisure time for pleasure : *her hobbies are reading and gardening*.

So, it could be that you just couldn't find the right dictionaries. For that, I have two suggestions:

- [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=hobby&ls=a) – which will provide links to several dictionaries all in one convenient place.
- [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/hobby) - which lists definitions pulled from a few different dictionaries, along with example usages, synonyms, hypernyms, and similar words.

Those are two excellent resources when trying to find more information about a particular word.

You had the right idea, though. *Playing sports, reading books, going fishing*, and *watching movies* could all be considered hobbies. *Hobby* is a versatile word, and can include strenuous activities such as rock climbing or hiking, sedentary activities such as quilting or reading, or exhilarating activities such as waterskiing or skydiving. It is often used in the context of collectors as well:

> *She collects coins as a hobby*.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Hobby means "shumi" in Japanese. The problem is that "shumi" seems to have a wider meaning than "hobby" does, and I don't know how wide it is. In order for me to properly use a word "hobby," I have to know what it is exactly. For example, sleeping a lot on Sundays is a "shumi."  Waching baseball games on TV is also a "shumi." They are all "an activity pursued in spare time for pleasure or relaxation," but do you call them "hobbies"?

Comment: I don't think most English speakers would classify Sunday naps as a hobby, except in a lighthearted comment. In other words, I can imagine saying to someone: _Naps on Sunday are my hobby_ (though I expect they'd chuckle in response); however, in a personal profile, it'd be rare to see anyone list _Sunday naps_ under "Hobbies." As for baseball, you might call baseball a "hobby" if you actively followed the standings and rooted passionately for a particular team, but just watching an occasional game on TV probably doesn't make baseball your "hobby." Hobbies tend to imply more active involvement.